# Mark Dynamically Created Checkbox Checked using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to develop roles and permissions in laravel. I can now make the roles work properly, however i just have an issue of marking the checkbox checked of the current permissions of the user.

This is my current controller code

```
    $role = Role::findOrFail($id);
    $perm = Role::findOrFail($id)->permissions;
    $permissions = Permission::all();

    return view('Roles.edit', compact('permissions', 'role', 'perm'));
```

and for my view

```
@foreach($permissions as $perms)
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="input-group m-input-group m-input-group--square">
         <input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="{{ $perms->id }}" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>{{ ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $perms->name)) }}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your variable names are really bad, so try to improve those so later you know what is going on :)

I would change this:

```
$perm = Role::findOrFail($id)->permissions;
```

to this one:

```
$rolePermissions = Role::findOrFail($id)->permissions;
```

then in your view, you will need to check if the current permission is contained in the `$rolePermissions` and add the `checked` attribute to the checkbox:

```
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="input-group m-input-group m-input-group--square">
         <input type="checkbox" name="permission[]"
                value="{{ $permission->id }}"
                @if(in_array($permission->id, $rolePermissions)) checked @endif /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <label>{{ ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $permission->name)) }}</label>
      </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

I guess your `$rolePermissions` is a set of `ids`. If it is not just get the ids from the collection:

```
$rolePermissions = Role::findOrFail($id)->permissions->pluck('id');
```